# Why am I able to take out, and put away Navi?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I noticed that if I'm standing still I can push the blue button, and bring Navi out, or put her away. What is the purpose of this, or is it just for looks?

Comment: AFAIK, it's just for the looks.

Comment: Guess it's Ocarina of Time's [chat gem](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Chat_Gem). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is quite irrelevant - it's just for looks.